# Как переписать txt2csv?

Tags: python, csv

Имеется txt файл в котором записаны строки:

```
а,b,c
1,2,3
5,4,6
6,8,9
```

Нужно перевести этот txt в сsv с разделителем ";".

Следующий код

```
import csv

lst=[]
with open('iris_with_headers.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split(',')

        lst.append(words)
f_csv = open('iris_with_headers.csv', 'w')

print(lst)

with f_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(f_csv)
    writer.writerows(lst)
```

делает это почему-то некорректно. В частности разные буквы одного слова почему-то разлетаются в разные ячейки

Comment: Можете привести воспроизводимый пример данных, который поможет воспроизвести проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решалась следующим образом, возможно, избыточным, но рабочим.

в объекте writer необходимо указать диалект, с явно указанным разделителем.
Если диалект с точкой с запятой неизвестен, то можно создать свой собственный. Итого:

```
    txt_list = [['sepal length in cm',
                 'sepal width in cm',
                 'petal length in cm',
                 'petal width in cm',
                              'class'],
 ['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa\n'],
 ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa\n'],....]

csv.register_dialect("semicol", delimiter=";")

with open ("iris.csv",'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect="semicol")
    writer.writerows(txt_list)
```

После этого кода имеется csv-файл, который можно проверить Pandas и убедиться, что он открывается только с разделителем ;

Answer (score 3):

В Pandas это делается легче:

```
import pandas as pd    #  pip install pandas

(pd.read_csv(r'd:\download\iris_with_headers.txt')
   .to_csv(r'd:\download\result.csv',sep=';',index=False))
```

Comment: В вопросе не говорится, что исходный файл - csv.

Comment: @Qwertiy, хммм, судя по содержанию - это очень похоже на CSV... Подождем уточнений от автора вопроса

Comment: Исходник именно txt-шник. И его надо переписать в CSV c разделителем ';'

Comment: Задача учебная, поэтому pandas использовать нельзя